# Send mail from a BASH Script and how to configure mail servers for Ubuntu

Tags: bash, email, smtp, sendmail, mail-server

I have multiple (read 10s) MySQL slaves running in a LAN. Obviously, I cannot monitor them automatically from an external systems.

So, I thought of setting up local BASH scripts that will send a mail alert when the replication fails. I got the BASH script for replication but now I am stuck at mailing part..

I installed mailutils in Ubuntu and tried to send a mail. But, I get the following error

"Your access to this mail system has been rejected due to the sending MTA's IP xx.xx.xx.xxx poor reputation"

I found out that I can overcome this by getting it out of the list. But, I have 10s of those IPs and may change over time. So, is there any other method to use some server to send mails without the worry of removing IPs from SPAMHaus list?

Comment: If your servers are blocked by Spamhaus, and you are doing nothing about it, you are a serious threat to the Internet. Please get your act together!

Comment: @tripleee By default All IPs of all ISPs are blocked by SpamHaus. We can unblock them using an online form they provide. I just don't want to do that!! And btw, the systems I speak of don't have static IPs..

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. When you say "blocked by Spamhaus" most people will interpret that to mean your IP addresses are listed in the SBL.  If you are on dynamic DNS, then you will be in the PBL, but also a number of other block lists; an accurate problem description would mention this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a smarthost, e.g. your provider's email server, and forward over it. That is, configure your local mail server (in Debian exim is the default, and I guess it's the same for Ubuntu) to use a smarthost for mail delivery and configure it for rewriting such that all mail from your system is locally forwarded to the accounts of the people dealing with your MySQL slaves and these people are aliased to external addresses.

This can be done via the `/etc/aliases` file, if I remember correctly.